# Find join point of two sequences

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm of a function that can return a point of the join of two sequences, for example:

`seq1=471 seq2=480`

However,

```
seq1=seq1+(4+7+1) =483

seq1=seq1+(4+8+3) =498

 ....and so on.
```

For the seq2 we do the same thing

```
seq2=seq2+(4+8+0) =492

 ....and so on.
```

We do that until we find the joining point, in our example the joining point is 519
so the main aim of the function is returning 519.
The function has 2 params (seq1,seq2) and returns an integer.

Comment: Is the seq1 and seq2 restricted to 3 digit integers only?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you have:

```
int getDigitsSum(int x)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (x != 0)
    {
        sum += x % 10;
        x /= 10;
    }

    return sum;
}

int findJoinPoint(int seq1, int seq2)
{
    while (seq1 != seq2)
    {
        if (seq1 < seq2)
        {
            if (seq1 == 0)
                return -1; // no chance to join, seq1 is 0

            seq1 += getDigitsSum(seq1);
        }
        else if (seq2 < seq1)
        {
            if (seq2 == 0)
                return -2; // no chance to join, seq2 is 0

            seq2 += getDigitsSum(seq2);
        }
    }

    return seq1;
}
```

This should work for any value of both seqs (incuding 0 and negative). For both seqs equal 0, function returns 0 - this seems to be logically proper.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
def compute_join_point(s_1, s_2):
  
  seq_1 = []
  seq_2 = []

  while True:
    seq_1.append(s_1)
    seq_2.append(s_2)
    if s_1 == s_2:
      return s_1
    s_1 = s_1 + sum(int(digit) for digit in str(s_1))
    s_2 = s_2 + sum(int(digit) for digit in str(s_2))
    if s_1 in seq_2:
      return s_1
    if s_2 in seq_1:
      return s_2

print(compute_join_point(34, 41))
```